# Adding game names to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Hello I'm doing a school assignment with these instructions

> Write a while loop that prompts users for their favorite game. When
>   they enter the name of the game, print a message to the screen and add
>   a line recording their log in a file called games.txt. Make sure each
>   entry appears on a new line in the file.

I'm having trouble making the loop ask multiple times instead of just adding the game over and over again. Also, I don't want the `games.txt` file to lose the previous games that were added.

---

This is my current code:

```
filename = 'games.txt'
print("When you want to finish adding games just type 'done'")
game = input('Whats your favorite game? ')

with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    while game != 'done':
        print(game)
        file_object.write(game + str("\n)
```

As you can see if I run it and I put "Destiny 2" as a game it will keep adding the destiny 2 to the file named `games.txt` until I stop the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have an infinite loop that writes the last game name entered in the file, indefinitely.

You must place the input prompt in the while loop.
I think it is better to collect all data in a list first, then write the file.

```
filename = 'games.txt'
print("When you want to finish adding games just type 'done'")

games = []
game = ''
while True:
    game = input('Whats your favorite game? ')
    if game == 'done':
        break
    games.append(game)

with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    for game in games:
        file_object.write(game + str("\n"))
```

Comment: But won't that cause a problem since 'game' is defined after the while loop?

Comment: After testing that code for a couple times I found that when I type 'done' it adds it to the list so I just added "games.remove('done')" after the first while loop

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I fixed it, sorry, I am just getting warmed up.

Comment: Hint: look at the last piece of code there s apostrophe missing and a parenthesis